# ActiveMQ - What is the TTL value of an Advisory Message?

Tags: activemq-classic, dead-letter

I need to know What is the TTL value of an advisory message ? I have around 17 thousand messages enqueued in my Advisory topics and it shows 0 dequeues messages. I want to get rid of these messages. What is the possible way to do that.

```
     <deadLetterStrategy>
       <.... expiration="300000"/>
     </deadLetterStrategy>
```

If there are no subscribers to these advisory topics, then do these messages stay in activemq store or memory ?
I want these messages out of activrmq

Answer (score 1):

EnqueueCount means how many messages were *sent* to the Advisory Topic. Advisory messages are not stored by the broker.

UPATED: That is ok, DequeueCount of zero (0) on a topic means that there were no subscribers when the message was published.

Comment: I have edited the question that where enqueued count show thousands of messages, dequeues count shows zero.